# Replace values in a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list with two values like below:
at 0: yesnonoyesyes
at 1: yes=1;no=0

I need to replace value in'0' with the values after '=' in '1'.
I have written below code:

Can somebody please help

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("truetruefalsefalsefalse");
list.add("true=Ja;false=Nein");
String string0 = list.get(0);
String string1 = list.get(1);
String[] split = string1.split(";");
String replace = new String();
for (String string : split) {
  if (string0.contains(StringUtils.substringBefore(string, "="))) {

    replace = string0.replace(StringUtils.substringBefore(string, "="), StringUtils.substringAfter(string, "="));

  }
}
```

Comment: *I do not know what your problem is (error description), so I must guess:* you are always replacing on the original string, you should be replacing on the new string (from last iteration). (assuming that rest of code is not interfering, `StringUtils` working as expected) `String replacement = string0; ... for( ... replacement = reaplacement.replace(...`

Comment: you are never changing values in you list or `string0`, you are just overwriting the variable `replace` based on the not changing value of `string0` so it has to replace old changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After replacement you are not assigning the value back to list. That might be the issue. 
Please have a look at the below sample implementation of your program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ReplaceValues{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("truetruefalsefalsefalse");
        list.add("true=Ja;false=Nein");
        String[] split = list.get(0).split(";");

        for (String string : split) {
          String combination[] = string.split("=");     
          list.set(0, list.get(0).replaceAll(combination[0], combination[1]));
        }

        for(String item:list){
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
JaJaNeinNeinNein
true=Ja;false=Nein
```

Note: This will not work if you have overlapping strings eg.

```
true=ja
ue=t
```

As it will replace the ue again with t and overall result will be broken.
That's need to be handled saperatly.